# how do i plot a regression tree in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I tried running a regression tree previously and it worked fine, but now I am unable to do so when I tried to plot it

```
regtree  <- tree(price~date+age+distance+stores+latitude+longitude, data = Estate.train)
summary(regtree)
plot(regtree) # to plot tree structure
text(regtree, pretty = 0)
```

The results given is

```
> plot(regtree) # to plot tree structure
Error in plot.tree(regtree) : cannot plot singlenode tree
```

How do I rectify this? It is definitely not a singlenode tree.

Comment: When you type `summary(regtree)`    how many terminal nodes are reported?

Comment: One, but i have successfully plotted a tree before. if it helps, i got my data here http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Real+estate+valuation+data+set

Comment: The variable names in the UCI data that you cited do not agree with the variable names in your `tree` statement.  Is it possible that the names in your data don't match.  When I run tree on this data,  I get 11 nodes.